# Why does C++ prohibit binding T1 && to T2 lvalue when T1 is reference-related to T2 (and T1 and T2 are not class types)?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, rvalue-reference

I'm exploring this question: Given `char * x`, why doesn't `const char * && rc2 = x` compile?

And I found [dcl.init.ref#5.4.4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4868/dcl.init.ref#5.4.4) which says (when we are binding `T1 &&` to `T2` lvalue where `T2` is not class type, ) and if `T1` is reference-related to `T2`, then if the reference is an rvalue reference, the initializer expression shall not be an lvalue.

Why is there a rule like this? What does this rule want to avoid?

---

I clearly know that bindings like `int i; int && ri = i;` is illegal, but my question here is, I expect `const char * && rc2 = static_cast<const char *>(x);` where `static_cast<const char *>(x)` should be an prvalue which can bind to rvalue references.

As `int i; double && rd = i;` is valid, why is `char * x; const char * && rc2 = x;` invalid?

Comment: pretty sure `const char * && rc2` is a `const` rvalue reference to a `char *`, not an rvalue reference to a `const char*`

Comment: @Jason I've been learning C++ for many years. I'm afraid it's my fault not to state my question clear enough so I add an update. My question is why `const char * && rc2 = x` cannot be treated as `const char * && rc2 = static_cast<const char *>(x);`

Comment: @XuanInsr I see, the part that you added in your updated question should be there in the original question. *Now* it is a bit clear what you're asking.

Comment: @NathanOliver I think not? A const reference would be `char * &&const rc2`, which is not a legal syntax.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat that is interesting - I believe that question was added after the downvotes and also the posted answer.

Comment: @DrewDormann The gist of the question didn't change though.

Comment: Related(for an lvalue reference instead of rvalue ref): [Error when Initialising a reference to a pointer to const string with pointer to a non-const string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520191/error-when-initialising-a-reference-to-a-pointer-to-const-string-with-pointer-to)

Comment: I think it's to avoid confusion. The very fact that your question got a -3 before your clarification is an indication how confusing this would be if it were allowed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule covers not only cases such as

```
int x;
int&& r = x;
```

but also

```
const int x = 0;
int&& r = x;
```

Here, we don't have an exact match in types: the reference wants to bind to an `int`, but the initializer expression has type `const int`. Just like how we don't want the first example to create a temporary `int` object (a copy of `x`) and then bind `r` to that, in the second example we also don't want a temporary `int` object to be created by copying `x`.

Or, similarly

```
struct Base { /* ... */ };
struct Derived : Base { /* ... */ };
Derived d;
Base&& b = d;
```

The idea is that if you have a reference binding that *could* have been a direct binding if only the reference were of the appropriate kind (i.e. an lvalue reference instead of an rvalue reference) and had the appropriate cv-qualification, then it's probably the programmer's mistake. Creating a temporary object is usually not the desired behavior.

Reference-relatedness captures this notion of "could have been a direct binding".

As for this case that you mentioned:

```
char * x; const char * && rc2 = x;
```

the same logic applies: the reference-relatedness tells you that this is "too close" to a valid reference binding. If you changed the type of the reference to `const char* const&`, then the binding would be valid.

Answer (score 0):

###### [The question seemed to boil down to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77295257/why-c-prohibits-binding-t1-to-t2-lvalue-when-t1-is-reference-related-to-t2/77295275?noredirect=1#comment136267009_77295275)

> why reference-related types are specially treated? :)

I don't know the answer to this, and I suspect that it's not explicitly written in the standard.

I can make the wild hypothesis:

- If `x` and `y` have reference-related types, that means you can lay them out in memory in the same way, so having `x` be a reference to `y` is possible, hence a thing like `X && x = y;` would surprise you, as editing `x` would change `y`, which you would not expect from an rvalue reference (unless you had consciously `std::move`d `y`, clearly).
- On the other hand, if `x` and `y` have types which are not reference-related, then a thing like `X && x = y;` requires a conversion of `y` from `Y` to `X` so you truly get a temporary, layed out somewhere else in memory, to which `X&&` *can* bind.

###### Below is the answer to the original question plus some of its edits

> Given `char * x`, why `const char * && rc2 = x` doesn't compile?

Because that's like any other `SomeType x; const SomeType && r = x;`, i.e. it's trying to bind an lvalue to an rvlue reference, and that's not allowed for the piece of standard you quoted.

> My question is, why there is a rule like this? What does this rule want to avoid?

It's not that it wants to avoid something. It's just the way of making the rvalue references actually useful.

After all,

- If an rvalue reference could bind to both rvalues and lvalues, it would be no different from `const&`, so why introducing it?
- If an rvalue reference could bind only to lvalues, it would be no different from (non-`const`)`&`, so why introducing it?

---

```cpp
int i;
double && rd = i;
```

works because `rd` is a reference to `double`, but the initializer is an `int`, so a temporary `double` is materialized by converting `i` to `double`, and *that* is a temporary.

**Notice that after those two statements, you shouldn't expect, and indeed it doesn't happen, that modifying `rd` results in modifying `i`.**

On the other hand, the case you mention originally, is more akin to (the reason being that even though the types are different in your case, `char*` vs `const char*`, they are still [reference-related](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.init.ref#4), because of [conv.qual](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.qual))

```cpp
int i;
int && rd = i; // illegal
```

If this was to work, then the two bullet points above would apply, and you'd be seeing the edits to `rd` be reflected in `i`.

However, if you were to do this

```
int i;
int && rd1 = static_cast<int>(x);
int && rd2 = static_cast<int&&>(x);
```

`rd1` is bound to a temporary (because of [expr.static.cast#1](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.static.cast#1)), not `i`, whereas `rd2` has write access to `i`.

Comment: But `static_cast<const char *>(x);` is also a temprorary

Comment: I'll add something on this, but incidentally I think that the use of `const char *` instead of a simpler type `int` is only complicating the matter for no gain.

Comment: Why do you say OP's case is more similar to your first example than the second? OP has two different types, after all.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but I think `const char * && rc2 = x` is not `SomeType x; const SomeType && r = x;` as it's not `char * const`

Comment: Thank you, I see your last edition, it finally comes my question: why reference-related types are specially treated? :)

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, I've tried to address that, but I'm not 100% sure I've pin-pointed the right bit of the standard.

Comment: The first example is still a bit different from what OP has, because they don't have a top-level const.

Comment: @XuanInsr, I've tried to make an hypothesis for the question in your last comment.